# Cannot seem to align content to top of cell

Tags: html, css

got an issue with an email I am designing. The header and main image are not aligning to the top of the cell. I believe I have removed all of the padding (there is a cell for image that only appears for mobile, but removing the cell has not removed the space) but there remains a gap between the Section title (FITNESS) and the content directly below.

I have attached an image showing what I mean.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS

```
[![<style type="text/css">
    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
    table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

    /* RESET STYLES */
    img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
    table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
    body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    a\[x-apple-data-detectors\] {
       color: inherit !important;
       text-decoration: none !important;
       font-size: inherit !important;
       font-family: inherit !important;
       font-weight: inherit !important;
       line-height: inherit !important;
    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'miso-regular';
    src: url('fonts/miso-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/miso-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'miso-bold';
    src: url('fonts/miso-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/miso-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    }



    /* MOBILE STYLES */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

     .img-max {
       width: 100% !important;
       max-width: 100% !important;
       height: auto !important;
     }

     .img-float {
            display:block;
            float:none;
            margin:0 auto 20px !important;
     }

     .max-width {
       max-width: 100% !important;
     }

     .mobile-wrapper {
       width: 85% !important;
       max-width: 85% !important;
     }

     .mobile-padding {
       padding-left: 5% !important;
       padding-right: 5% !important;
     }

     /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
     .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
     }

    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
 .mobile-show {
    display: none !important;
 }

}

    /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
    div\[style*="margin: 16px 0;"\] { margin: 0 !important; }
    </style>][1]][1]
```

HTML

```
<table border="0" bgcolor="#e8ebee" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 550px;" class="responsive-table">
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- ARTICLE TITLE -->
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 5px 0 5px; line-height: 25px; font-family: 'Stardos Stencil', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color: #98a4ae; text-transform: uppercase;" class="padding">FITNESS</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- ARTICLE IMAGE -->
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; color: #666666;" class="padding"><img alt="insert alt text here" class="img-max mobile-show" height="264" src="images/article-long-mobile.png" style="display: block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #999999;" width="100%"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- ARTICLE COPY -->
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" style="padding: 0 5px -20px 5px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif; color: #666666; vertical-align:top" class="padding"><div style="vertical-align: top"><!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="160" align="right" style="width:160px;"><tr><td style="padding:0 0 20px 20px;">
<![endif]-->
    <img alt="insert alt text here" class="img-max mobile-hide img-float" src="images/article-long.png" align="right" style="display: block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #999999; vertical-align: top; Margin:0 0 20px 20px;" width="200px">
<!--[if mso]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->

<p align="center" style="font-size: 50px; line-height: 50px; font-family: 'miso-bold'; color: #666666;">Why &quot;Skipping&quot; Legs Is Better Than Hitting 1000 Steps</p><p align="center" style="padding: 0 5px 20px 5px; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px; font-family: 'miso-regular'; color: #98a4ae;" class="padding">Whether you squat or snatch, press or curl, biggest hitters or resistance hitters</p></div>

Runti iur aute di blaccum et qui odi oditia sa dem quibus vento cum aut aut volor sitempo ribusae consequos et idenis alia dia diti ant mi, occum consequi nonet od excepel iquatiorpore liquatur, nia nam eossitas poribusda nimagnis alibus, ute vellor moloriori dis et adit volorio. Iliquid modia doluptati ipicaes ipiendunt ex et incimustrume eariatati ditatem porentist apiendit, od eos as eicimpore eniet ad que deliquatem.Runti iur aute di blaccum et qui odi oditia sa dem quibus vento cum aut aut volor sitempo ribusae consequos et idenis alia dia diti ant mi, occum consequi nonet od excepel iquatiorpore liquatur, nia nam eossitas poribusda nimagnis alibus, ute vellor moloriori dis et adit volorio. Iliquid modia doluptati ipicaes ipiendunt ex et incimustrume eariatati ditatem porentist apiendit, od eos as eicimpore eniet ad que deliquatem.Runti iur aute di blaccum et qui odi oditia sa dem quibus vento cum aut aut volor sitempo ribusae consequos et idenis alia dia diti ant mi, occum consequi nonet od excepel iquatiorpore liquatur, nia nam eossitas poribusda nimagnis alibus, ute vellor moloriori dis et adit volorio. Iliquid modia doluptati ipicaes ipiendunt ex et incimustrume eariatati ditatem porentist apiendit, od eos as eicimpore eniet ad que deliquatem.Runti iur aute di blaccum et qui odi oditia sa dem quibus vento cum aut aut volor sitempo ribusae consequos et idenis alia dia diti ant mi, occum consequi nonet od excepel iquatiorpore liquatur, nia nam eossitas poribusda nimagnis alibus, ute vellor moloriori dis et adit volorio. Iliquid modia doluptati ipicaes ipiendunt ex et incimustrume eariatati ditatem porentist apiendit, od eos as eicimpore eniet ad que deliquatem.Runti iur aute di blaccum et qui odi oditia sa dem quibus vento cum aut aut volor sitempo ribusae consequos et idenis alia dia diti ant mi, occum consequi nonet od excepel iquatiorpore liquatur, nia nam eossitas poribusda nimagnis alibus, ute vellor moloriori dis et adit volorio. Iliquid modia doluptati ipicaes ipiendunt ex et incimustrume eariatati ditatem porentist apiendit, od eos as eicimpore eniet ad que deliquatem.Runti iur aute di blaccum et qui odi oditia sa dem quibus vento cum aut aut volor sitempo ribusae consequos et idenis alia dia diti ant mi, occum consequi nonet od excepel iquatiorpore liquatur, nia nam eossitas poribusda nimagnis alibus, ute vellor moloriori dis et adit volorio. Iliquid modia doluptati ipicaes ipiendunt ex et incimustrume eariatati ditatem porentist apiendit, od eos as eicimpore eniet ad que deliquatem.Runti iur aute di blaccum et qui odi oditia sa dem quibus vento cum aut aut volor sitempo ribusae consequos et idenis alia dia diti ant mi, occum consequi nonet od excepel iquatiorpore liquatur, nia nam eossitas poribusda nimagnis alibus, ute vellor moloriori dis et adit volorio. Iliquid modia doluptati ipicaes ipiendunt ex et incimustrume eariatati ditatem porentist apiendit, od eos as eicimpore eniet ad que deliquatem.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: Can you give me the project with the image? i will try my best....

Comment: This code is very confusing. **Tip:** do not use table to do layout. **Tip 2:** you almost never need to use the *!important* directive in CSS.

Comment: Thank you Maruf for the offer, though Андрей Лобанов has fixed it for me now. Also @eldes what do you mean by not using tables to do layout? This is how I have built emails generally.

Comment: Sorry, @schro. I had not noted to be an email marketing piece. Thus, to be compatible with the various mail applications, it is really necessary - unfortunately - to use tables and CSS within the style attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin-top: 0;` to the paragraph with heding.

```
<p align="center" style="font-size: 50px;line-height: 50px;font-family: 'miso-bold';color: #666666;margin-top: 0;">Why "Skipping" Legs Is Better Than Hitting 1000 Steps</p>
```